# After moving server and IP, stylesheets and other resources not found (404 errors in fiddler)

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, orchardcms-1.6

I have moved an Orchard CMS site from one host and server to another host and server. The IP address is obviously different.

All the files have been correctly copied and the correct html is rendered.

However, all the styles sheets produce a 404 error. I repeat that the files are where they should be.

Indeed, any other resource, such as images or stylesheets produce the same problem. Again, the files are all in place.

Can anyone think what could be causing this. Nothing has changed other than the server and IP.

I have another orchard site on the same IP and server that is working fine. However, it was not moved from a different server.

I ping for the site and it comes up with the correct IP address for the new server

### EDIT:

Not sure that this is Orchard specific, although something related to Orchard's themes and how they work *could* be to blame...  But I really can't see what.

It sounds much more like an IIS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server people got back to me.  They changed the "website to 4.0 Integrated Pipeline mode." and all now works.  Go figure.

I am sure I had checked that it was in Integrated Pipeline mode, but hey ho.

Comment: What does that even _mean_?  What a crock of BS -- "unexplainage server breakage on/off" is **not a feature**. I hate technobabble that doesn't actually relate to the business usecase -- it's the last refuge of proprietary-solution leeches, their slimy salespeople, & vendor lockin.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the CSS files, by entering their URLs into the browser address-bar directly?

Try "Copy image location" or from the Image Properties, of one of the failed images. Again, can you get this if you enter it direct into the browser?

Check the URL of failed resources, against the URL of working HTML resources or dynamic pages. make sure there are no differences in webapp path or context..

You'll also need to try Ctrl-R reloading.

There could also possibly be some caching in the way.. that might be holding the "404" or "not found" results, even after the content has moved. Try & shutdown/ or force refresh all server & proxy caches.

Comment: In fiddler, I see 404 errors for any resource request.  The same happens if I enter the url to the resource in the browser address bar directly.

Comment: Is this meant to be the exact same domain, but now from a different server? Do the HTML resources that appear to work, still work if you Ctrl-R them? We want to know we're not seeing _spurious success_ in our troubleshooting.

Comment: the correct html gets rendered.  But any resource file, such as .css, .js or .png, isn't found.  I have done ctrl-r in the browser window, ctrl F5 and F5.  No changes

Comment: I am increasingly convinced that this is an IIS issue.  As such it is out of my hands, as with the hosting package, I have no access to configure IIS.  The host support team have decided to "inform Senior Admin", whatever that means (probably that they don't have a clue)

Comment: Permissions, server setup, or resources in the wrong place. If the HTML is dynamic, maybe the server needs config as to where to serve resources from? Look in the server logs.. you should see a whole lot of 404s? Beyond that, it's Orchard and IIS that need to be configured.

Comment: I can't look in the server logs given the hosting package.  A very similar app (ie, it uses Orchard CMS) works fine, the only difference is that it was not transferred from a different server

Comment: see my answer below:  they changed to integrated pipeline mode (the server people that is) and all works.  Go figure.